# mvn javac invalid target 1.8 with Java 7 on Mac

Tags: java, macos, maven, compilation, javac

I have Mac OS X 10.10.3, with jdk 1.7 and jdk 1.8 installed. I want to compile my project under 1.7. So I set

```
# export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)"

# java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)

# mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T15:57:37+04:00)
Maven home: /Public/Java/apache/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.7.0_72, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

And I get the following error:

```
...
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project commons-amq: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
```

I checked maven debug (`mvn -debug`):
And I see the following output:

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
...
  <source default-value="1.5">1.8</source>
  <target default-value="1.5">1.8</target>
...
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile' with basic configurator -->
...
[DEBUG]   (f) source = 1.8
[DEBUG]   (f) target = 1.8
...
```

I checked POM file and there is no 1.8 specification there. `config.xml` file is absent.

So is it possible to know what is the source of compiler properties `source` and `target`? Why in my case source == target == 1.8?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/trouble-shooting/jdk-being-used-is-different-than-expected.html

Comment: does your pom specifiy a parent?

Comment: You are using a Java 1.7 JDK which implies you want to code in Java 1.7. But in your configuration you have wished to work with JDK 1.8 which you haven't installed or not correctly configured (JAVA_HOME).

Comment: Yes, pom specifies a parent. But in parent javac version is not specified. I supposed that fork=true can cause problems but I even checked env in new environment and it seemed to be ok:
    `$ echo $JAVA_HOME
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7/Contents/Home`

    `$ java -version
    java version "1.7.0_72"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)`

Comment: Java version properties was defined in parent `pom.xml`.